# Adding '/' to url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Can someone please tell me what should i write to my .htaccess file so that '.php' gets replaced with '/'.

I have searched the whole net and i really can't find the particular answer.

also, i want to replace query strings like '?key1=value1&key2=value2' with '/?key1/value1/key2/value2/'

I have spent my whole day searching for an answer but couldn't find any.

Comment: So you want to [remove the PHP extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588022/htaccess-to-remove-php-extension-godaddy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the query string, you can use these rules to replace the **&** and **=** from your query string:

```
# replace all of the "="
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1/%2 [N]

# replace all of the "&"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1/%2 [N]

# ensure there's a trailing "/" at the end of the query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%{QUERY_STRING}/ [N]
```

This will take the request: `/something?a=b&c=d&e=f` and rewrite it to: `/something?a/b/c/d/e/f/`

Comment: you missed replacing '.php' extension with '/'. but I guess there are already many posts on the internet regarding that, thanx for ur input, really appreciate that.. :)